# Formas de ordenar ascendentemente los números de un array

Tags: c#

Estoy revisando unos programas que tengo hechos, y uno tiene la función de ordenar tres números ascendentemente en un `array`, yo lo he hecho con una función "built-in" pero me gustaría saber si hay forma de hacerlo manualmente.

Aquí el código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array1 = new int[3];
            Console.WriteLine("Entra els nombres");    
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            {
                array1[x] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            ordena(array1);
        }

        static void ordena(int[] array1)
        {
            Array.Sort(array1);
            Console.WriteLine("Els nombres ordenats son:");

            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(array1[x]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Manualmente" si con ello quieres decir mediante funciones que tu mismo hagas claro que se puede; solo es cuestión las implementes; sin embargo te sugiero considerar las que en C# están disponibles. Algunos nombre de forma de ordenar es "Burbuja", "Quicksort", (jajaja son los que recuerdo); en fin salvo requieras algo complejo no disponible reitero uses lo ya existente.

Comment: De hecho ya lo haces, la ordenación la hace el método `Sort()`, justo en la primer línea de tu método `Ordena` usando `Array.Sort(array1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de implementar un orden en los items del array, podrias hacer uso de la clase `Array`

[Array.Sort()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6tf1f0bc(v=vs.110).aspx)

entonces seria

```
Array.Sort(array1);
```

O sino podrias usar linq

[Sorting Operators in LINQ](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/linq/linq_sorting_operators.htm)

```
int[] array2 = array1.OrderBy(x=> x).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

con una Expresión lambda

```
int[] sortedCopy = myArray.OrderBy(i => i).ToArray();
```